# Creating an array from two different arrays with dot product

Tags: python, numpy

Given is X (n,d) array and theta(k,d) array and a parameter temp_parameter.

In my code, I want to create a matrix such that its i,j component is the dot product of the ith row of X and the jth row of theta. I have created this so far

```
k = theta.shape[0]
n = X.shape[0]
zeros = np.zeros((k,n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(k):
        zeros[j][i]= np.dot(X[i],theta[j])/temp_parameter
```

However, this is extremely inefficient. Can anybody give me a hint how to improve my code?

Comment: I might need to add that numpy is imported as np.

Comment: Expected input and output always helps to test with. Like what is `k`, `n` and `temp_parameter`, and what do you expect `zeros` to be after your code?

Comment: I get the result desired for relatively "small" k and n but when it comes to k and n being over 10000 my program will not terminate even after 3 hours and temp_parameter is an integer.

Comment: I understand. I'm asking: could you provide a "small" demonstrative `k`, `n` and `temp_parameter` for us so _we_ can run your program to see what it's supposed to do? It's a lot easier to test solutions against a known than the unknown.

Comment: `np.einsum('nd,kd->nk', X, theta)` or `X @ theta.T`.

Comment: I think you just want to multiply by the transpose (matrix style) then divide (element wise): `theta @ X.T / temp_parameter`

Comment: @QuangHoang This is exactly what I need but if I want to take the transpose of this matrix what would I have to change in the parameters and why?

Comment: Simplest is `(X @ theta.T).T`, or `(theta @ X.T)`. Or with `np.einsum`, use this string instead: `'nd,kd->kn'`.  I'll leave you figure the *why* part.

Comment: give us a [mcve].  Then we can show both your iterative results and a fast version.